# Cannot remove email using Accounts Package in Meteor

Tags: meteor, accounts

When trying to use one of the basic Accounts methods listed below on the server-side, I always get an error of the following type:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'removeEmail'

**Server Methods:**

- Accounts.addEmail()
- Accounts.removeEmail()
- Accounts.findUserByUsername()
- Accounts.findUserByEmail()

I have tried from inside the app and from the REPL shell.

**Accounts-related packages I use:**

- meteor-platform
- accounts-password
- accounts-facebook
- pauli:accounts-linkedin
- accounts-twitter
- splendido:accounts-emails-field
- accounts-base
- alanning:roles

Comment: Just wanted to add my 5 cents here, i also ran into similar problem and still didn't find a way. Seems like it is not available if you run it in callbacks like `onCreateUser`. When ran on server side (not in publish callbacks), the part you are looking for is `AccountServer`.

The docs say you can make a subclass on `AccountsCommon` and implement your own userId() if you want, but dunno how..

You can see exactly what happens here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running a Meteor version prior to Meteor 1.2. I *think* all of the functions you mention were added in 1.2. To check your meteor version, run:

```
meteor --version
```

If that isn't the problem, please provide the exact code that is causing the error you mentioned.

FYI, the following shows that those methods exist in my Meteor 1.2 installation with the packages you mentioned:

```
[brettle@localhost test-app]$ meteor --version
Meteor 1.2.0.2
[brettle@localhost tmp]$ meteor create test-app
Created a new Meteor app in 'test-app'.       

To run your new app:                          
  cd test-app                                 
  meteor                                      

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here:
  https://www.meteor.com/learn                

[brettle@localhost tmp]$ cd test-app

#### Note "meteor add accounts-password" also works instead of this next line: 

[brettle@localhost test-app]$ meteor add accounts-password accounts-facebook pauli:accounts-linkedin accounts-twitter splendido:accounts-emails-field accounts-base alanning:roles

Changes to your project's package version selections:

accounts-base                    added, version 1.2.1
accounts-facebook                added, version 1.0.6
accounts-oauth                   added, version 1.1.7
accounts-password                added, version 1.1.3
accounts-twitter                 added, version 1.0.6
alanning:roles                   added, version 1.2.14
ddp-rate-limiter                 added, version 1.0.0
email                            added, version 1.0.7
facebook                         added, version 1.2.2
localstorage                     added, version 1.0.5
npm-bcrypt                       added, version 0.7.8_2
oauth                            added, version 1.1.6
oauth1                           added, version 1.1.5
oauth2                           added, version 1.1.5
pauli:accounts-linkedin          added, version 1.1.2
pauli:linkedin                   added, version 1.1.2
rate-limit                       added, version 1.0.0
service-configuration            added, version 1.0.5
sha                              added, version 1.0.4
splendido:accounts-emails-field  added, version 1.2.0
srp                              added, version 1.0.4
twitter                          added, version 1.1.5


accounts-password: Password support for accounts
accounts-facebook: Login service for Facebook accounts
pauli:accounts-linkedin: Accounts service for LinkedIn accounts
accounts-twitter: Login service for Twitter accounts
splendido:accounts-emails-field: Adds to the user obj a `registered_emails`
field containing 3rd-party account service emails.
accounts-base: A user account system          
alanning:roles: Authorization package for Meteor
[brettle@localhost test-app]$ meteor &        
[1] 21185
[[[[[ ~/tmp/test-app ]]]]]                    

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20151007-23:49:34.554(-7)? ** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
I20151007-23:49:34.555(-7)? ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
I20151007-23:49:34.555(-7)? ** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
I20151007-23:49:34.555(-7)? ** will still be sent to all clients.
I20151007-23:49:34.555(-7)? **
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? ** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? **
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? **   $ meteor remove autopublish
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? **
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? ** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? ** for each collection that you want clients to see.
I20151007-23:49:34.556(-7)? 

[brettle@localhost test-app]$ meteor shell

Welcome to the server-side interactive shell!

Tab completion is enabled for global variables.

Type .reload to restart the server and the shell.
Type .exit to disconnect from the server and leave the shell.
Type .help for additional help.

> Accounts.removeEmail
[Function]
> Accounts.addEmail
[Function]
> Accounts.findUserByUsername
[Function]
> Accounts.findUserByEmail
[Function]
```

Comment: You're of course right. That was the reason. Thanks