# Cannot add email using Accounts package in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, accounts

When trying to use some of the basic accounts methods in meteor,

- Accounts.addEmail
- Accounts.setUsername

I always get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Accounts.[function] is not a function`

This is confusing since other Accounts methods such as Accounts.createUser work as expected.  Some other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973790/cannot-remove-email-using-accounts-package-in-meteor) mentioned that this might have to do with meteor being out of date.  This is not the case as I am running the latest version (1.2.1).

Also, if I start up the `meteor shell` command and search for either Accounts.addEmail or Accounts.setUsername, the shell states that they are indeed functions.

The relevant packages I am using are:

- accounts-password
- accounts-ui

Comment: You are most likely calling the functions from the browser/client-side. These functions only work on server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Blaze said in comment, both methods you mentioned are server-side only as you can see in [meteor doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-setUsername). As Meteor does not ship with a built-in roles package, it allows you to ensure those methods are called by the right person according to your liking. You'll have to use `Meteor.call('foo')` to call these methods while ensuring security or permissions.

For example:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addNewEmail: function(email) {
        'use strict';

        Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, email);
        Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(this.userId, email);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This piece of code makes sure the guy calling the method will add an email to himself and not somebody else. You could also use some extra checks by using `alanning:roles`.